# Perl: RegEX: Capture group multiple times

Tags: regex, perl

I'm developing a piece of code to filter a text as follows:

```
    <DATA>
    .SUBCKT SVI A B C D E F
    + G H I
    + J K L
    .....
    + X Y Z
    *.PININFO AA BB CC
    *.PININFO DD EE FF
    <DATA>
```

I need the output to be

```
    A B C D E F
    G H I
    J K L
    .....
    X Y Z
```

I already made a regular expression to do so:

```
m/\.SUBCKT\s+SVI\s(.*)|\+(.*)/gm
```

The problem is that I have many similar sections like this input but I only need to detect `+` lines which are following `.SUBCKT SVI` header not any other header.

How I could match group many times like `(\+\s+(.*))`. I want to match this repeated capture group as it repeated many times.

Any advice to get this expression.

Comment: You have to define `"any other header"` and `plus lines` .. Continuity, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is closer to what you need.

```
m/\.SUBCKT\s+SVI\s(.*)\n(\+\s+(.*)\n)*/gm
```

Comment: The pointed I tried expression similar to yours but it doesn't work. How I could match group many times like `(\+\s+(.*))`. I want to match this repeated capture group as it repeated many times. I tried to add `*` at end of expression as you did but I got none at the output. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I made use of @shawnt00 answer and modified the regular expression and it made the job.

```
\.SUBCKT\s+SVI_TRX201TH\s(.*\n(\+\s+.*\n)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? Note that it stops at the `.....` because it doesn't begin with a `+` or `.SUBCKT`

It won't handle the case where a range of `+` lines is immediately followed by another `.SUBCKT` line; is that a problem?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  next unless my $in_range = s/^\.SUBCKT\s+// ... /^[^+]/;
  next if $in_range =~ /E/;

  s/^\S+\s+//;
  print;
}

__DATA__
<DATA>
.SUBCKT SVI A B C D E F
+ G H I
+ J K L
.....
+ X Y Z
*.PININFO AA BB CC
*.PININFO DD EE FF
<DATA>
```

**output**

```
A B C D E F
G H I
J K L
```

---

**Update**

Here's a state machine version that deals with the special case described above

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $state;

while ( <DATA> ) {

  if ( /^\.SUBCKT\s+\S+\s+(.+)/ ) {
    $state = 1;
    print $1, "\n";
  }
  elsif ( /^\+\s+(.+)/ ) {
    print $1, "\n" if $state;
  }
  else {
    $state = 0;
  }
}

__DATA__
<DATA>
.SUBCKT SVI A B C D E F
+ G H I
+ J K L
.SUBCKT SVI A B C D E F
+ M N O
+ P Q R
*.PININFO AA BB CC
*.PININFO DD EE FF
<DATA>
```

**output**

```
A B C D E F
G H I
J K L
A B C D E F
M N O
P Q R
```